# Sorting tableview rows using coredata

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, core-data

I have used coredata to store names in a tableview. I have sorted the rows and it is working. The problem is when i add a row to the table view, the row is being added and also sorted. But the new row is not sorted with the old rows. Here is my code.

---

```
import UIKit
import CoreData
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource {


@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

var people = [NSManagedObject]()

let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    title = "Hit List"
    tableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
}

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    let managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Person")
    let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "name", ascending: true)
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]
    do {
        let results = try managedContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest)
        people = results as! [NSManagedObject]
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("Could not fetch \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
    }
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return people.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell")
    let person = people[indexPath.row]
    cell?.textLabel?.text = person.valueForKey("name") as? String
    return cell!
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let context = appDelegate.managedObjectContext
    context.deleteObject(people[indexPath.row] as NSManagedObject)
    people.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
    do {
        try context.save()
    } catch let error as NSError  {
        print("Could not save \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
    }
    //tableView.reloadData()
    // remove the deleted item from the `UITableView`
    self.tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
}

@IBAction func addName(sender: AnyObject) {

    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "New Name", message: "Add a new name", preferredStyle: .Alert)
    let saveAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Save", style: .Default, handler: { (action:UIAlertAction) -> Void in
        let textField = alert.textFields?.first
        self.saveName(textField!.text!)
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    })

    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel",
        style: .Default) { (action: UIAlertAction) -> Void in
    }

    alert.addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler {
        (textField: UITextField) -> Void in
    }

    alert.addAction(saveAction)
    alert.addAction(cancelAction)

    presentViewController(alert,
        animated: true,
        completion: nil)
}

func saveName(name: String) {

    let managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext
    let entity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Person", inManagedObjectContext: managedContext)
    let person = NSManagedObject(entity: entity!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: managedContext)
    person.setValue(name, forKey: "name")
    do {
        try managedContext.save()
        people.append(person)
    } catch let error as NSError  {
        print("Could not save \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
    }
}
}
```

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The array is not sorted because the new person is only appended to `people`

You have four options:

1. Append the person, sort `people` in place.

   ```
   do {
     try managedContext.save()
       people.append(person)
       people.sortInPlace { ($0.valueForKey("name") as! String) < ($1.valueForKey("name") as! String) }
       self.tableView.reloadData()
   } catch let error as NSError  {
      print("Could not save \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
   }
   ```
2. Don't append the person, refetch the data via `NSFetchRequest` (like in `viewWillAppear`)
3. Insert the person into `people` at the appropriate index with the `orderedInsert` algorithm
4. Use `NSFetchResultController` and its delegate methods (there are many tutorials how to do that).

After each of the four options reload the table view.

Comment: can you tell me the answer elaborately

Comment: I added code for option #1, the code for option #2 is the same as in `viewWillAppear` (you could write a reusable function). Providing code for the other options is too extensive, there are many tutorials and examples here on SO and the www.

Comment: i am getting this error when i use sortinplace.  **Value of type 'NSManagedObject' has no member 'name'**

Comment: I recommend to use a subclass of `NSManagedObject` to be able to access the properties directly, but I updated the answer to the `valueForKey` syntax.